# how to compare 2 List<Entity>?

Tags: java

I have **2 List entities**, I don't want to compare it by nested loop if it possible,

let say I have entities like this :

```
List<Entity1> = entity1Repository.findByCode(String code);
List<Entity2> = entity2Repository.findByName(String name);
```

and I want to compare those entities, I want the result of the list which that List only value which has the same value,

such as this= `[1, 2, 4]` and `[1,2,5]`
and i want the result like this  ==> `[1,2]`

how to do that in *Java*?

Comment: If Entity1 and Entity2 have no common supertype (Emtkty Interface) you can use Object in the below answers and must write a static helper function which extracts and compares the values `static boolean isSameEntityValue(Entity1 es, Entity2 e2)`

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function that returns a list containing intersecting  elements of 2 list passed as paramters:

```
public <T> List<T> intersection(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();

        for (T t : list1) {
            if(list2.contains(t)) {
                list.add(t);
            }
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Comment: what is public  `<T>` mean ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming input:

```
List<Integer> l1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4);
List<Integer> l2 = Arrays.asList(11, 2, 5, 4);
```

Listing two ways:

```
    //method 1
    List<Integer> result = l1.stream().filter(l2::contains).collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(result);

    //method 2
    Set<Integer> s1 = new HashSet<>(l1);
    s1.retainAll(l2);

    System.out.println(s1);
    System.out.println(l1);
```

In method1: you are using streams, a wonderful concept from java

In method2: you are creating another set, and calling retainAll() on it. This will remove other elements from s1, but no affect on original list l1.

Comment: will it work also in List<Customer1Entity> and  List<Customer2Entity> ? because your example is List<Integer>, i am stil very new about Java

Comment: Your class: "Entity" must have at least the method: 
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {...}

Comment: can u give example how to write this on the entity ? i have tried it but still don't understand and now rok

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java 8 Stream api to get common elements from two lists.

`List<Entity> commonEntity = entity1.stream()
    .filter(entity2::contains)
    .collect(Collectors
    .toList()));`

Comment: should i write Entity of one of them on the List<Entity> commonEntity ??

Comment: it should be type of the elements you wants to compare. Ex: If you comparing two lists of type String resulted list type will be String.